# Erro na query: 'SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, pdo

Estou fazendo chamada de dados da base de dados com php e PDO , mas sempre que eu o faço com `bindparam();` dá-me o seguinte erro:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''SELECT * FROM
>   dados' LIMIT 0,'5'' at line 1' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\paginacao\index.php:25 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\paginacao\index.php(25): PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\paginacao\index.php on line 25

Aqui em baixo teem o código, para ajudar:

```
<?php
require_once "class.user.php";

$liga = new USER();
$busca = "SELECT * FROM dados";

// nÃºmero de registros por pÃ¡gina

$total_reg = "5";
$pagina = $_GET['pagina'];

if (!$pagina)
    {
    $pc = "1";
    }
  else
    {
    $pc = $pagina;
    }

$inicio = $pc - 1;
$inicio = $inicio * $total_reg;
$limite = $res = $liga->runQuery(':busca LIMIT :ini,:totalreg');
$res->bindparam(':busca', $busca, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$res->bindparam(':ini', $inicio, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$res->bindparam(':totalreg', $total_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$res->execute();
$todos = $res1 = $liga->runQuery(":busca");
$res1->bindparam(":busca", $busca);
$res1->execute();
$tr = $res1->rowCount($todos);

// verifica o nÃºmero total de registros

$tp = $tr / $total_reg;

// verifica o nÃºmero total de pÃ¡ginas // vamos criar a visualizaÃ§Ã£o

while ($dados = $limite->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    $nome = $dados["nome"];
    echo "Nome: $nome<br />";
    } // agora vamos criar os botÃµes "Anterior e prÃ³ximo"
$anterior = $pc - 1;
$proximo = $pc + 1;

if ($pc > 1)
    {
    echo " <a href='?pagina=$anterior'><- Anterior</a> ";
    }

echo "|";

if ($pc < $tp)
    {
    echo " <a href='?pagina=$proximo'>PrÃ³xima -></a>";
    }

?>
```

Onde está o problema que causa esse erro?

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está concatenando a primeira consulta como parâmetro do tipo string, ou seja, você está dizendo que o código

```
SELECT * FROM dados
```

é na verdade uma string, e não uma consulta, para resolver você pode adicionar o código inteiro na primeira variável (já que você realiza o filtro por limite todas as vezes):

```
$busca = "SELECT * FROM dados LIMIT :ini,:totalreg";
$limite = $res = $liga->runQuery($busca);
$res->bindparam(':ini', $inicio, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$res->bindparam(':totalreg', $total_reg, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$res->execute();
```

Comment: Agora diz isto:  
**Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''5'' at line 1' in D:\xampp\htdocs\paginacao\index.php:24 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\paginacao\index.php(24): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\paginacao\index.php on line 24

Comment: O segundo parâmetro estava como string, mudei o tipo do PDO para PARAM_INT, altera lá no seu código.

Comment: já fiz isso, também não deu :/

Comment: já consegui! tirei as aspas da variável $total_reg e já funciona . Muito obrigado :)